# How to convert Bouncy Castle SCrypt Byte array to String format or HexString format?

Tags: java, arrays, cryptography, bouncycastle, scrypt

**Bouncy Castle SCrypt Java API**.

```
byte[] sCryptHash = SCrypt.generate(plaintextPassword.getBytes(), salt.getBytes(), 16384, 8, 1, 1024);
String str = sCryptHash.toString();
```

The above generate method gives `byte[ ]` format, I need to store it in database as a String,
`toString()` does not help in comparing, I expect some characters issue in `toString()`.

Is there a way to convert it to String Safely ?

Any other alternative to Bouncy Castle ?

Comment: `new String(sCryptHash);`  should work. Because it is a normal byte Array. or if you Need a hex representation you can use `org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex.toHexString(sCryptHash)`

Comment: Hey Jens that helps, can you put it as answer so that it can be marked as solved.

Comment: Have done it. ..

Comment: new String(sCryptHash); this gives unreadable characters.
org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex.toHexString(sCryptHash) helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a hex representation you can use `org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex.toHexString(sCryptHash)`